# Native view below UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

In Apple's music app there is a `UIView` below the `UINavigationBar`. I've attached an image with what I'm talking about circled in red. Is this something I can add natively--kind of like `inputAccessoryView` on `UITextField`'s?

The reason I would want it like this is because I wouldn't have to worry about the placement of cells in my `UITableViewController` and such, as well as future patching headaches with new iOS releases.

[image: playlist view]

Comment: I think it's just a semi-transparent view with 3 buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do it is subclassing UINavigationBar and add a subview with the menu. I use to do it this way and it's easy and useful

Comment: Thanks! Not what I was looking for but useful information none-the-less.